# why equal partitioned data works faster?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

`repartition()` redistribute the data among different nodes with new partitions and `coalesce` does the same thing but it keeps the some of original partitions without shuffling and add others partitions within those.

Why its always a say in spark that, equally partitioned data will be processed faster. Any reason why is it so and why it wont in case of not evenly distributed datasets ?

what's stopping `not evenly distributed datasets` to process faster ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'partition' of data is processed by a 'task' as part of a 'stage'. A stage has many tasks that run in parallel. A Spark 'app' consists of multiple stages. The next stage can only start when the prior stage has completed.

A large partition has more data to process and takes longer simply therefore. Resources are in some cases held longer exclusively (un)necessarily.